# Is there any option to read SAS files meta.column types using pyreadstat

Tags: python-3.x, sas

I have using pyreadstat library to read data and metadata of SAS data files. With respect to metadata, I can list out column names, length & labels but not column types.

My requirement is to read complete metadata details from SAS data.

Please help if there is option in pyreadstat library itself to get column types.

Comment: Are you pulling these files from a SAS server or from a SAS7bdat file? If a SAS server of some kind you can use the dictionary tables to get this information, which are SAS data sets. You probably know this as well, but SAS only has two data types, numeric/character.

Comment: The manual for that package says it makes this:  `original_variable_types : a dict of variable name to variable format in the original file. For debugging purposes.`

Answer (score 1):

When you read a sas file with pyreadstat, you get a metadata object, "meta" in this case:

```
import pyreadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat("sample.sas7bdat")
```

You can use meta.original_variable_types. This will give you the column data format from SAS. SAS has only two types: character and numeric. The later can have many formats that regulate how they are displayed in SAS.

You will get formats such as '$' for a character column, 'BEST' for numeric, 'YYMMDD' for date, 'DATETIME' for datetime, 'TIME' for time, etc. These formats. are the ones that SAS saves as information in the sas7bdat file.

You can see all the information you can get in the metadata object in the documentation: https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html